# Проблема редактирования БД через PDO (PHP)

Tags: php, html, база-данных, pdo

Код не выдает ошибок, но не редактирует базу данных. Проблем в коннекте нет, но все равно добавил, если понадобится. Начинаю вставку кода с того, что нажал на кнопку показывающую пассажиров.( там все работает без проблем)

index.php

```
if (isset($_POST['passangers'])) {?>
        <div class='tablicaPassangers'><br>
            <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5 align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'>Уник.Номер</td>
                    <td align='center'>Гос. номер</td>
                    <td align='center'>Тип машины</td>
                    <td align='center'>Имя заявителя</td>
                    <td align='center'>Время подачи</td>
                    <td align='center'>Время возвращения</td>
                    <td align='center'>Маршрут</td>
                    <td align='center'>Адрес</td>
                    <td align='center'>Количество пассажиров</td>
                    <td align='center'>Водитель</td>
                    <td align='center'>Статус</td>
                    <td align='center'>Настройка</td>
                </tr>
                <?
                require_once('connect.php');
                require_once('logik.php');
                foreach ($passanger as $mas) {
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$mas['id']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['state_number']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['typeCar']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['name_applicant']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['filing_date']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['return_date']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['route']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['address']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['count_passengers']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['driver']."</td>
                        <td>".$mas['status']."</td>
                        <td><a href=edit.php?keye=".$mas['id']."> Редактировать</a></td>
                        </tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </table>
```

logik.php

```
  <?php
  require_once('connect.php');

  $sql="select * from passengers";
  $Data=$pdo ->query($sql);
  $passanger=$Data->fetchAll(); ?>
```

connect.php

```
  <?
  $host = 'localhost';
  $db   = 'disp';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $charset = 'utf8';

  $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
  $opt = array (
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
  );
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
      ?>
```

edit.php

```
<?
require_once('connect.php');
require_once('logik.php');
if (isset($_GET['keye'])) {
    $kl = $_GET['keye'];
    $sql = "select * from `passengers` where `id` = ?";
    $Data=$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $Data->execute(array("$kl"));
    $line=$Data->fetchAll();

    

echo "<form name='my_form1' method='POST' action='ed.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$line['id'].">
    <input type='text' name='name_applicant' value=".$line['name_applicant'].">
    <input type='date' name='filing_date' value=".$line['filing_date'].">
    <input type='date' name='return_date' value=".$line['return_date'].">
    <input type='text' name='address' value=".$line['address'].">
    <input type='text' name='count_passengers' value=".$line['count_passengers'].">
    <input type='submit' name='ok10' value='save'>
</form>";
```

}
?>

ed.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['ok10'])) {
    require_once('connect.php');
    require_once('logik.php');
    $sql = "UPDATE `passengers` SET `name_applicant` = ?, `filing_date` = ?, 
    `return_date` = ?, `address` = ?, `count_passengers` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
    $Data = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
    $Data -> execute(array("$_POST[name_applicant]", "$_POST[filing_date]", 
    "$_POST[return_date]", "$_POST[address]", "$_POST[count_passengers]", "$_POST[id]"));
    
}
?>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
```

Comment: Если в `ed.php` сделать `var_dump($_POST)`, то там все значения будут, которые необходимы?

Comment: Проверил, id возвращает 0. array(7) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["name_applicant"]=> string(4) "gasg"....

Comment: Собственно, вот и проблема

Comment: Также посмотрите `var_dump($line)` в `edit.php`

Comment: А как это происходит? Разве id не должен автоматически подвязываться. Ведь я его привязывал даже в форме в edit.php.

Comment: посмотрите `var_dump($line)` в `edit.php` и посмотрите отличия между методами [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) и [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php), который, как раз, вам и нужен, скорее всего

Comment: Спасибо, заменил fetchAll на fetch и заработало

Answer (score 1):

Заменил fetchAll на fetch в edit.php